# Exposing Standard pages and standard record view page in salesforce sites

Tags: visualforce, site.com

Can we/ How to expose these standard pages, standard record view in salesforce sites ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only way to directly expose native Salesforce tabs on a site, without re-creating them via VisualForce, is to setup a Salesforce Community using the "Salesforce Tabs + VisualForce" template.

That template looks identical to the standard Salesforce Classic look and feel, and allows you to add/remove tabs similar to how you would within SFDC for internal users. Your community can be public (not behind a password barrier), or private (users must have a Salesforce login).

Of course, this will only be a possible solution for you IF your org has Communities. If you don't have communities or have no interest in setting up communities, then you'd need to create some custom VisualForce pages and then add them to a Force.com Site

**More info on Salesforce Tabs + VisualForce:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_tabs_vs_community_designer.htm

**General Communities Implementation Docs:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/communities_intro.htm

I hope this helps!